# AWS SAM CLI Fresh install throws error - dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python

Tags: python, homebrew, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to use the AWS SAM CLI installed through Homebrew and I am seeing the following error when I try to use sam with any command:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.53.0/libexec/bin/python3.7
  Reason: image not found
```

Looking at the `.Python` file referenced in the error, it is symlinked to a python folder that doesn't actually exist:

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 RCR  staff   224 Jun 16 19:40 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 RCR  staff   288 Jul  8 14:55 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 RCR  staff    70 Jun 16 19:40 .Python -> ../../../../opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
drwxr-xr-x  39 RCR  staff  1248 Jul  8 14:55 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 RCR  staff    96 Jun 16 19:40 include
drwxr-xr-x   3 RCR  staff    96 Jun 16 19:40 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 RCR  staff    61 Jun 16 19:40 pip-selfcheck.json
```

I do not have a `3.7` folder at that location, but I do have a `3.8` folder. That said, I am not sure what is the origin of this folder. My Python3 installation is from Homebrew and located in the Cellar as usual (`../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.3_1/bin/python3`) and symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/python3`. Not sure if that is relevant but I figure more info can't hurt.

I tried symlinking the `.Python` file to the `3.8` version I do have at that location but it only produced other errors.

Any idea how I can get this CLI working?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like 0.53.0 comes with python3.7 executables, there is a workaround until it is fixed:

```
brew install --build-from-source aws-sam-cli
```

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/2101

https://github.com/aws/homebrew-tap/issues/93

Comment: This works for me ```brew reinstall --build-from-source aws-sam-cli```

Comment: Ha, those github issues where both added just after I stopped looking there and come and ask here. Anyway. This seemed to do the trick. I assume that later down the line, when there is an update without the issue, `brew upgrade` will be enough?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (but not a fresh install). I updated brew today and **sam** stopped working.

Until someone posts a fix, here's a workaround that worked for me:

```
pip3 install aws-sam-cli
```

Comment: May I ask where you found that you could install using just pip3? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up ditching homebrew for `aws-sam-cli`.

```
% brew uninstall aws-sam-cli
% pip3 install aws-sam-cli --user
```

I also had to add `/Users/**MY_USER_NAME**/Library/Python/3.7/bin` to my `$PATH`.

```
% vi ~/.zshrc

# Add
export PATH="/Users/**MY_USER_NAME**/Library/Python/3.7/bin:$PATH"

% source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to upgrade the SAM CLI

`brew upgrade aws/tap/aws-sam-cli`